# Restore-SPSite exception: SPStoredProceduresContent

Tags: 2013, powershell, restore

I'm trying to restore a site collection backup from one server to a different server in powershell, but I get the following error:

Restore-SPSite : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPStoredProceduresContent' threw an exception.

My command looks like this:

Restore-SPSite -Identity [URL] -Path [BACKUP PATH] -Force

Both machines are running the same version of SharePoint 2013, and can't even find a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.SPStoredProceduresContent anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Could have been my VM running out of memory? 8GB just ain't enough, geez... bumping to 10GB and the problem goes away. Maybe coincidence.